# How to query the date in Bookshelf.js

Tags: javascript, sql, orm, bookshelf.js

I'm using the Bookshelf.js ORM and I need be able to query by date and having some issues.

here is a samples code snippet that I'm using.

```
      this.model.query((q) => {
            q.where('created_at', '>=', Date.now());
            q.orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
        })   
        .fetch().then(function (model) {
            socket.send(JSON.stringify(model));
        });
```

The above code just returns a null or empty array. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is really a pity your query returns empty results, querying in the **future** is a very nifty feature to have.

But I think you want data created in the **past**, right? So try

```
this.model.query((q) => {
  q.where('created_at', '<=', new Date());
  q.orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
})   
  .fetch().then(function (model) {
     socket.send(JSON.stringify(model));
  });
```

Note also `Date.now()` that gives the [milliseconds elapsed since the UNIX epoch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) was replaced by `new Date()` that gives the proper current date/time.

Anyway, the criteria makes not much sense either because it basically means *all rows*. Unless, of course, you are looking after some bug on `created_at` column or filtering out `NULL` attributes.